# Image in binary in the data to WordPress media library

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

A specific API, returns an image in binary in the data.

If I need to save it to the server, I can easily do it by following the code.

```
$response = curl_exec($curl); // This is the API response
file_put_contents('example2.png', $response);
```

How can I add it to the WordPress media library?

Comment: The media library doesn't show files, it shows posts of type `attachment`, what you're asking about is called sideloading in the WordPress API. Just Putting images in the uploads folder on its own won't make them show up in the media library, and it's easier to give WP a file from a temporary folder that it can move into the preferred location by itself and generate the various image sizes

Comment: @TomJNowellAs Thanks, As I understand, I need to give the URL of the image to download to media_sideload_image function. So here do I need to file_put_contents and then media_sideload_image or is there any way to pass to binary response to directly to `media_sideload_image` ?

Comment: if you want to use that function yes, but there are other and better functions such as `media_handle_sideload`, there is no reason to download a file here

Answer (score 0):

You should use `media_handle_sideload`. Write your file out to the filesystem then use `media_handle_sideload` to process it in the same way any other upload is processed. Be sure to cleanup afterwards.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/#comment-983 for an example